# CasperJs test can't found css selector (test broke after migrate from jade to pug)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, pug, casperjs

I migrate my templates from jade to pug then all casperJs tests are falling. Most errors are about the css selectors that are not found. here an example of my code :

casperJs test:

```
casper.thenOpen("http://localhost:8080/activites/E5555", function() {
    this.wait(5000, function() {
      this.click("a.open-user-dialog");
    });
  });
```

and here the pug for the element:

```
p
    i.fa-icon-plus.fa-icon-success 
    strong: a.open-user-dialog(href="#user-dialog", data-toggle="modal") Add user
```

here the test result:

**FAIL Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector: a.open-user-dialog**

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured it out, here the answer: 
I put `casper.wait(2000, function(){});` before loading the page and it fixed the problem.

```
casper.wait(2000, function(){});
casper.thenOpen("http://localhost:8080/activites/E5555", function() {
    this.wait(5000, function() {
      this.click("a.open-user-dialog");
    });
  });
```